# Unable to resolve dependencies while ROS Install on Mac

Tags: ros, ros-indigo, macosx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to install ROS Indigo on Mac OS X El Capitan and am following [this](http://wiki.ros.org/action/login/indigo/Installation/OSX/Homebrew/Source) tutorial. However, along the tutorial I am getting suck at the step 2.1.2 wherein I need to run the following command:

```
$ rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro indigo -y
```

Upon doing so, I get the following error:

```
$ rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro=indigo -y
executing command [sudo -H pip install -U urlgrabber]
Password:
Collecting urlgrabber
  Using cached urlgrabber-3.9.1.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/tmp/pip-build-iJQJmX/urlgrabber/setup.py", line 3, in <module>
        import urlgrabber as _urlgrabber
      File "urlgrabber/__init__.py", line 54, in <module>
        from grabber import urlgrab, urlopen, urlread
      File "urlgrabber/grabber.py", line 427, in <module>
        import pycurl
    ImportError: No module named pycurl
    
    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-build-iJQJmX/urlgrabber/
ERROR: the following rosdeps failed to install
  pip: command [sudo -H pip install -U urlgrabber] failed
```

I tried looking for help, but am not able to get through. Does anyone have a clue why?

Thanks :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/242101/unable-to-resolve-dependencies-while-ros-install-on-mac/) by [dexter05](https://answers.ros.org/users/27787/dexter05/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2016-08-20

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on 2016-08-21**:
You may wanna use this script instead: https://github.com/mikepurvis/ros-install-osx Has been working great for many many people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried Mike Purvis's solution and it works!  Thanks for the tip [spmaniato](http://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/)! It takes a long time though. Just a tip for all those who might need help in the future. Packages like pyqt, sip may throw ImportError during compilation. A simple `brew unlink <package that throws ImportError> && brew link <same package>` works like magic.

---

Originally posted by [dexter05](https://answers.ros.org/users/27787/dexter05/) with karma: 26 on 2016-08-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0